# Download a text file and assign the text as a string to a variable - Angular 7

Tags: javascript, angular

I have an API response that contains inside a link to a stored text file in the cloud.
I want to download the text file and use the text as a string inside my Angular application.
This what i did so far(Not much)

```
getTextDetails(resultId: string) {
    this.http.get(TEXT_DETAILS_URL + resultId).subscribe((res: any) => {
        this.saveTextFile(res.textFile);
    });
}


// The data is a link to the text file!!
saveTextFile(data) {
    const blob = new Blob([data], { type: 'text/csv' });
    const url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
}
```

Any help will be appreciated.

[Edit]

Thanks for your help i didn't knew that it's that simple. I got a small issue now that I'm receiving:

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0 at JSON.parse (<anonymous>) at XMLHttpRequest.onLoad
```

Comment: i don't understand the question. is `res.textFile` not already a string with the text in your Angular Application?

Comment: @RenéDatenschutz Thanks for your'e help! No its a path to the text file in the cloud. I just need to assign the text inside this file to a string.

Comment: do you want to read the file content and use it ur angular applicaton ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I understand, there are two API calls. The first API call returns the path to the text file. You use this path to make another API call to get the actual contents of the file.

Please do correct if my understanding is not correct.

If my understanding is correct, give this a try:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { switchMap } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  name = 'Angular';

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.getFileData()
      .subscribe(response => console.log(response));
  }

  getFileData() {
    return this.http.get('/assets/filePath.json')
      .pipe(
        switchMap((response: any) => this.http.get(response.pathToFile, {
          responseType: 'text'
        }))
      );
  }

}
```

---

**NOTE:** Do understand that I'm using the response from a locally hosted JSON file which again points to a locally hosted text file. Also, you'll have to specify the `responseType` for the second API call as `text`.

---

> Here's a [**Working Sample StackBlitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-read-text-file-via-api-call?file=src/app/app.component.ts) for your ref.

Answer (score 0):

In order to get the text file. You can do:

```
text: string;    

getTextDetails(resultId: string) {
        this.http.get(TEXT_DETAILS_URL + resultId).subscribe((res: any) => {
            //Now get the text from url.
            this.http.get(res.textFile).subscribe(text: any) {
              this.text = text;
            }
        });
    }
```

Now you can display this text in your html template.

```
<p ngIf*="text"> {{ text }} </p>
```